# Cast array to smaller size array

Tags: java, arrays

I am getting a image from the camera that I store in a byte array. I am passing this byte array to a native function.

Problem: The image contains color information that the native function does not care about. The black/white information is located in the first half of the array.

So basically what I would like to do is:

```
byte[1000] image;
nativecall((byte[500])image);
```

The reason behind this is that a call to jni function means a memcopy of my image. With 30 fps I could save some time and memory if I only pass the relevant part of the image.

The constraint to any solution is that both arrays must point to the same array/memory. So simply creating a copy of the first half of the array to a smaller array is not an option.

Could something like this be done with a WeakReference?

Comment: It's been a very long time I haven't used JNI, but couldn't you simply pass the array and the index in the array where the meaninful information starts? The native code could then make a copy of the relevant part only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try to [GetByteArrayElements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#wp17382) in your jni code. Depending on JVM implementation it either copies the array or gives you a direct pointer to it in java memory. I only used it with android, and it did give me a direct pointer, but I don't know if it works now with HotSpot.

If it fails, [nio direct buffers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#nio_support) are another way to share memory between java and jni code without copying.

Comment: I think using nio with direct buffers is in fact the best solution to the problem here.

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to have even considered the obvious answer, which is to pass the length as well as the array to the native method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing the image you get in a byte[1000] array, store it in 2 byte[500] ones from the outset, then  simply pass the one you're interested in to your native function.

You can make a helper class like

```
class MyImage {
    public byte[500] grayInfo;
    public byte[500] colorInfo;
}
```

Since array length is not part of the type, casting can not help here.